# Javascript: make an deep clone/extend/copy function that does not make any garbage for GC

Tags: javascript, object, garbage-collection, clone, real-time

I would like to make an extendDeep() function that does not make any garbage for GC.

The garbage collector need to be as inactive as possible. 
ref.: https://www.scirra.com/blog/76/how-to-write-low-garbage-real-time-javascript

This is the extendDeep() function I want to modify:

```
function extendDeep(parent, child) {
    var i, toStr = Object.prototype.toString,
        astr = "[object Array]";

    child = child || {};

    for (i in parent) {
        if (parent.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if (typeof parent[i] === 'object') {
                child[i] = (toStr.call(parent[i]) === astr) ? [] : {};
                extendDeep(parent[i], child[i]);
            } else {
                child[i] = parent[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return child;
}
```

The function does not have to return anything. since the retuned object is why the garbage is made.

It is assumed that all the propertis of the parent object is available by reference (reuse of objects)

Comment: How is this function creating garbage in the first place? It never throws out anything it creates! (note about the returned "child" object: in the case where you already receive the object from somewhere else, returning it does no harm and in the case you receive no second argument, the problem is calling this function in the first place, since doing so is pointless if the caller ignores the return value)

Comment: Huh, what do you expect? Cloning an object obviously has to create a new object (and doing it deep, actually a lot of them). If you want to be memory-efficient, just do not use that function. Do you actually have a performance problem? Then please show us that problem, not how you think it should be solved.

Comment: I fail to see anything related to garbage collection when you create an object. Garbage collection is about destroying un necessary or unreachable objects, what are you doing that needs to be garbage collected ? nothing.

Comment: @missingno its the "child[i] = (toStr.call(parent[i]) === astr) ? [] : {};" that creates a new object or array. the new objects only has one reference. so when I delete the reference to the object, it will be garbage.

Comment: @Borune:Ah, now I see. The culprit is the toStr.call isn't it?

Comment: I am using this function 30 time a sec with many objects.

Comment: @missingno: the toStr.call(parent[i]) === astr just checks true if is an array. i am not sure about the culprit :)

Comment: I think I see a solution: I have to find an allready existing object or array to copy into the child. anyhow the function is not going to be generic... gotta log for today. thanks for the coaching :)

Comment: @Borune: Yes, that function inevitably creates new objects. As said before, rather show us the code that uses this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a more interesting question than I first thought. After reading the suggested link it is clear the articles author is advocating object pooling. So something like

```
function Pool(fConstructor, nMaxSize, fCleanFunction) {
    this.aObjectPool = [];
    this.nMaxSize = nMaxSize;
    this.fCleanFunction = fCleanFunction;
    this.fConstructor = fConstructor;
}

Pool.prototype.get = function() {
    return this.aObjectPool.pop() || new this.fConstructor();
}

Pool.prototype.recycle = function(oObject) {
    if (aObjectPool.length < this.nMaxSize) {
        fCleanFunction(oObject);
        this.aObjectPool.push(oObject);
    }
}       

function wipeArray(aArray) {
    aArray.length = 0;
}

function wipeObject(oObject) {
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            delete obj[p];
        }
    }
};

var oArrayPool = new Pool(Array, 50, wipeArray);

var oObjectPool = new Pool(Object, 50, wipeObject);
```

could be used to implement the pool. Then you'd replace the []'s and {}'s in the extend deep function with pool.get()'s.

Of course, for this to work you'd also need to ensure you were recycling old objects and arrays rather than just leaving them for garbage collection.

Comment: Nulling the properties (e.g. `= undefined;`) would be better than deleting them, as the article update states. See [farre's comment](https://www.scirra.com/blog/76/how-to-write-low-garbage-real-time-javascript?page=2#comment5916)

Comment: Probably true, although it's not quite the same thing (If you're using the object as a map for example.). Pooling would provide the best benefit when the objects being constructed are more complex. Ultimately any tweaks like this would need to be tested in the environment they'll be used as there is a huge number of variables that could affect the overall performance benefit, if any.

Answer (score 1):

A JS interpreter might avoid creating a string when doing `toStr.call(parent[i])` but if you can't rely on them doing that optimization then you can avoid creating strings in the very common case by changing

```
toStr.call(parent[i]) === astr
```

to

```
parent[i] instanceof Array  // Is a regular array.
|| (!(parent[i] instanceof Object)  // Is cross-frame
    && 'number' === typeof parent[i].length  // Might be an array
    && toStr.call(parent[i]) === astr)  // So check the hidden [[Class]] property.
```

If you know you're dealing with objects created by constructors from the same frame (so no cross-frame object sharing) then you can get by with just

```
parent[i] instanceof Array
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1st thing you need to decide is whether you want a clone or a copy, they are 2 different things.

The code you have given does a copy (and not a great one, because the use of hasOwnProperty means you could easily end up with non functional copies). A clone would be something like.

```
function Clone(){}
function clone(object) {        
    Clone.prototype = object;

    return new Clone();
}

var objectToClone = {};
var clonedObject = clone(objectToClone);
```

The difference being that for a copy, changes to the original object will not affect the copy. For a clone, changes to the original object will affect the clone unless the clone has overwritten the property.

Comment: I don't think you should refer to *prototypical inheritance* (with `Object.create`) as "cloning".

Comment: Calling it a clone is easier than calling it "an object that inherits all properties from another object". Have you got another term you'd suggest? On another note, I've been coding away blithely unaware that Object.create does exactly what my Clone method does, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Calling it a "Facade" or something might fit better, but I don't want to start inventing terms here. A huge downside of the inheritance (used for copying) is that it does not release the original for being garbage-collected, even when you would not need it any more. Also, creating long inheritance chains will have a worse effect than creating new objects with own properties.